# When we reduce an adverbial clause, does the two clauses always have to be linked in some way besides having the same subject?

Tags: grammar

*... Considerable decreases were witnessed in the figures for India and China seven years later, with Asian elephant populations of around 7500 and 500 respectively. **Sinking even more dramatically, Asian elephant numbers in Malaysia and Thailand both declined by around 60%...***

Normally, in a sentence with a reduced adverbial clause, I see a causal, temporal, or contrasting relationship between the clauses. The second sentence sounds right to me, but I can't tell for sure which relationship it is here. Is the sentence unnatural?

[image]

Comment: Are you claiming there's no relationship between "Sinking even more dramatically" and "Asian elephant numbers in Malaysia and Thailand both declined by around 60%"? They are both expressing the same fact, the latter more specific than the former. Here "Sinking even more dramatically" functions to link the main clause to the preceding sentence.

Comment: I thought the two clauses had to have one of the three relationships: causal, temporal, or contrasting relationship. That's why when I couldn't tell which relationship they had, I doubted if it was correct. So it seems that we have more than three kinds of relationships between the clauses, don't we?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "reduced adverbial clause". In your example, the participial clause "sinking even more dramatically" is not reduced in any way, and nor is it a modifier. It's a supplement (or appendage) functioning as an adjunct in clause structure. The supplement clause is not syntactically linked to the main clause, but there is of course a semantic relationship.